# How to run PHPUnit tests?

Tags: 7, testing

[Drupal 8 is supplementing](http://drupal.org/phpunit) the testing framework based on [Simpletest](http://drupal.org/simpletest) with [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/), and Simpletest could be [removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1567500) in Drupal 9.

I'm not upgrading yet to Drupal 8, but I was wondering how I can write existing tests in PHPUnit (to follow-up with the trend) for Drupal 7, instead in Simpletest?

Is there any method or module for integrating PHPUnit with Drupal 7?

There are few like [phpunit](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpunit) or [drunit](https://www.drupal.org/project/drunit), but they're not for Drupal 7.

Comment: Just want to throw Behat out there. It's great for doing real-world test scenarios (not really unit testing): https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalextension Once you get it setup, it makes testing Drupal functionality a breeze. We are running Behat in a CI environment and love it!

Comment: @donutdan4114 can you provide some more info or an instructional video showing how you accomplish this with Drupal?  I am very interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get PHPUnit tests to run by bootstrapping Drupal within each of your test files. It's not ideal, but it does work.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'your/path/to/drupal');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';

// Bootstrap Drupal.
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// Proceed with PHPUnit tests as usual from here.
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  ...
```

Comment: If you need to do this, what you are writing are not Unit Tests, and you should probably just use DrupalWebTestCase from the SimpleTest-based core testing module.

Comment: @matt2000 yea and wait hours until tests finished ...

Answer (score 3):

PHPUnit provides a nice API for building the objects whereas the Drupal's simpletest doesn't. There is [one library available in gist for integrating PHPUnit with Drupal 7](https://gist.github.com/andreiashu/5567877).
To execute those scripts you need to checkout this [gist-repository](https://gist.github.com/andreiashu/5567877). To execute Unit-Tests in the command-line simply go to a Drupal site (ie. `<DRUPAL_ROOT>/sites/default`) and use **dphpunit.bash** just as you would use the phpunit command.

The script consists of 3 files:

1. **dphpunit.bash** - which simply invokes drun-dphpunit.php with a few extra parameters. It's needed because PHP is incapable of dealing with symlinks correctly.
2. **drun-dphpunit.php** - which is basically the same as the upstream phpunit runner, except that it handles the extra parameter.
3. **bootstrap.inc.php** - which makes a Drupal bootstrap very similar to drush.

Source: http://devblog.more-onion.com/content/writing-unit-tests-drupal-7

---

#### `bootstrap.inc.php`

```
<?php

$path = CWD;

$site_dir = NULL;
$dpl_dir = NULL;

while ($path != '/') {
    if (file_exists($path . '/settings.php')) {
        $site_dir = $path;
    }
    if (file_exists($path . '/index.php') && file_exists($path . '/includes/bootstrap.inc')) {
        $dpl_dir = $path;
        break;
    }
    $path = dirname($path);
}

if (!$dpl_dir) {
    echo "No drupal directory found in or above current working directory. Aborting. \n";
    exit(1);
}
if (!$site_dir) {
    $site_dir = $dpl_dir . '/sites/default';
    if (!file_exists($site_dir . '/settings.php')) {
        echo "No configured site found. Aborting.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = basename($site_dir);
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $dpl_dir);
set_include_path($dpl_dir . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

#### `dphpunit.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

# get dirname of the script
DIR="$(dirname $(readlink "$0"))"

# assume the boostrap script is stored in the same directory
php "$DIR/drun-phpunit.php" "$(pwd)" --bootstrap "$DIR/bootstrap.inc.php" "$@"
```

#### `drun-phpunit.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php';
PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()->addFileToBlacklist(__FILE__, 'PHPUNIT');

if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
  xdebug_disable();
}

if (strpos('/usr/bin/php', '@php_bin') === 0) {
  set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
}

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
define('PHPUnit_MAIN_METHOD', 'PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main');
define('CWD', $_SERVER['argv'][1]);
unset($_SERVER['argv'][1]);

$command = new PHPUnit_TextUI_Command;
$command->run($_SERVER['argv']);
```

---

There is one more library available for integration PHPUnit with Drupal 7: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit

More information about this scripts can be checked here: http://thomaslattimore.com/blog/using-phpunit-with-drupal-7

Comment: Sadly, this repo is gone.

Comment: -1 because gist is gone.

Answer (score 1):

## There is workaround with configuration file.

1. Create **phpunit.xml.dist** file in your drupal project root. Got to contain this

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
>          bootstrap="drupal_phpunit_bootstrap.php"
>          verbose="true">
>
> </phpunit>
> ```

2. Phpunit has to bootstrap our drupal instance. Create drupal phpunit bootstrap file. I prefer to name it **drupal_phpunit_bootstrap.php**

> ```
> <?php
>
> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'your.url';
> $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/index.php';
> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
> $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';
> $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = NULL;
> $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = NULL;
> $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = NULL;
> // Fix for behat drupal instantiation.
> define('DRUPAL_ROOT', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)));
> require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
> drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
> ```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/permanovd/cb9c02920c49a29c97653f4f697147b1

**Thats all. Now you can start your tests in several ways.**

#### 1. CLI

phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist QuestionValidationValueOptionsInputTest /yoursite.dir/public_html/profiles/standard/modules/some_module/tests/QuestionValidationTest.php

where:

- **-c**: Defines configuration file.
- **QuestionValidationValueOptionsInputTest and path**: Defines test class name and path to it.

#### 2. IDE (phpstorm)

You have to add test running configuration

[image: Test run configuration]

And no need to include drupal bootstrap code into every test.

### Note

You may have problems with tests because of wrong php version of your environment.

### Further reading:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html